# Delta compatible shoes and KEO pedals

Tags: pedals, shoes

I am planning to by these [cycling shoes](http://www.decathlon.in/cycling/cyclist-wear/footwear/cycling-shoes-500/p-M8243683) which claims `"Restriction of use:Only compatible with Delta Pedals and Cleats"`.

Reading up about Delta and Keo I understand that Keo pedals and Delta cleats are not compatible and vice versa. However, I could not find if the Keo cleats can be fit on these shoes.

So I guess my question is, if I buy these shoes and Keo pedals+cleats, can I fit the 3-hole Keo cleats on to the 3-holes in the shoes? In other words, are the dimensions and size of the 3-holes same in Keo and Delta?

Hope I make sense. Thanks!

Comment: The seller is an individual and does not have the cleats available to check right now. We are trying to get hold of some keo cleats but thought more knowledgeable folks here might be able to help. Have reached out to Decathlon, waiting for a response from them.

Comment: if if was possible to fix Keo cleats to these shoe, don't you think its strange that Decathlon go out of their way to say "Only compatible with Delta Pedals and Cleats" in their description?

Comment: Maybe. I will have my hands on the shoes and cleats, hopefully both delta and keo in a few days and report back.

Comment: Hole positions for Keo and Delta are exactly the same. I've switched over 3 years ago and the shoes didn't cause any problem.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Carel. Can you please make this an answer so I can accept it and you receive the credit you deserve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hole positions for Keo and Delta are exactly the same. I've switched over 3 years ago and the shoes didn't cause any problem.Even Shimano cleats of the 3-hole type have exactly the same pattern for the holes. And with the adapter Speedplay cleats will fit too.